# Regular Expression (regex). How to ignore or exclude everything in between?

Tags: java, regex

I have this input text:

```
142d  000781fe0000326f BPD    false    65535 FSK_75     FSK_75     -51.984   -48
```

I want to use regular expression to extract 000781fe0000326f and -51.984, so the output looks like this

```
000781fe0000326f-51.984
```

I can use `[0-9]{5,7}(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)` and `([-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])` to extract `000781fe0000326f` and `-51.984`, respectively.
Is there a way to ignore or exclude everything between `000781fe0000326f` and `-51.984`? To ignore everythin that will be captured by the non greedy filler (.*?) ?

```
String ref="[0-9]{5,7}(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)_____([-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])";

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ref,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
            while (m.find())
            {
                String all = m.group();
                //list3.add(all);
            }
```

Comment: If the format of the input is fixed you could you use `split("\\s+")` instead and extract 1st and 7th elements of the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you example data you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` to match either one of the regexes in you question and then concatenate them.

Note that in your regex you could write `(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)` as `[a-z][a-z0-9_]` and you don't have to escape the dot in a character class.

For example:

`[0-9]{5,7}[a-z][a-z0-9_]*|-?\d*\.\d+(?![-+0-9.])`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R3YkvH/1)

```
String regex = "[0-9]{5,7}[a-z][a-z0-9_]*|-?\\d*\\.\\d+(?![-+0-9.])";
String string = "142d  000781fe0000326f BPD    false    65535 FSK_75     FSK_75     -51.984   -48";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

String result = "";

while (matcher.find()) {            
    result += matcher.group(0);
}

System.out.println(result); // 000781fe0000326f-51.984
```

[Demo Java](https://rextester.com/ZQZW77956)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to combine strings together like that in *pure regex*, but it's easy to create a group for the first match, a group for the second match, and then use `m.group(1) + m.group(2)` to concatenate the two groups together and create your desired combined string.

Also note that `[0-9]` simplifies to `\d`, a character set with only one token in it simplifies to just that token, `[a-z0-9_]` with the `i` flag simplifies to `\w`, and there's no need to escape a `.` inside a character set:

```
String input = "142d  000781fe0000326f BPD    false    65535 FSK_75     FSK_75     -51.984   -48";
String ref="(\\d{5,7}(?:[a-z]\\w*)).*?((?:-?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+\\d.]))";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ref,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find())
{
  String all = m.group(1) + m.group(2);
  System.out.println(all);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot really ignore the words in between. You can include them all.
something like this will include all of them.

> [0-9]{5,7}(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*([-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9.])

But that is not what you want.
I think the best bet is either having 2 regular expressions and then combining the result, or splitting the string on spaces/tab characters and checking the 'n'th elements as required